# Django QuerySet displays improper string

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have a problem when I'm rendering a ManyToMany field in my view.

#Models:

```
from django.db import models


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content


class Drink(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

#View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Drink, Ingredient


def index(request):
    drinks = Drink.objects.all()
    context = {'drinks': drinks}
    return render(request, 'drinks/index.html', context)
```

#Template:

```
{% for i in drinks %}
    <h3>{{ i.title }}</h3>
    <p><b>Description:</b> <br>{{ i.description }}</p>
    <p>{{ i.ingredient.all }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is my web-site:

```
Screw driver

Description: 
Good drink made of pure vodka and California cultured oranges.

<QuerySet [<Ingredient: Vodka>, <Ingredient: Orange juice>]>
```

I cannot find any proper way to filter or format the last string. 
Is there anyone who has an idea?

Comment: You already know how to iterate over `drinks`. Why not do the same with `i.ingredient.all`? They are both querysets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over ingredients too.

```
{% for i in drinks %}
    <h3>{{ i.title }}</h3>
    <p><b>Description:</b> <br>{{ i.description }}</p>
    {% for j in i.ingredient.all %}
       <p>{{ j }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```